# battery recalibration tool Sony Vaio, battery Li-ion

Tags: battery, vaio, sony

I`m searching for recalibration battery tool for Li-ion battery of my Sony Vaio laptop. Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Battery last for max. 10 min. there is just just 2 ways to solve it: 1 . recalibrate and check  2. move battery to trash :)